# Como obter o GetModuleBaseAddress de um processo em C++?

Tags: c++, windows

Estou tentando pegar o GetModuleBaseAddress de um processo que estou tentando monitorar, porem não estou conseguindo por que tenho os offsets, adiciono eles porem não funciona, se eu apenas acessar o processo ai sim consigo, porem tenho que procurar onde esta alocado todas as vezes que reiniciar o programa.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <TlHelp32.h>


DWORD HP = 0x0072CFB0;
DWORD pid;
int value;

DWORD GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD dwProcessIdentifier, TCHAR* lpszModuleName)
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessIdentifier);
    DWORD dwModuleBaseAddress = 0;
    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = { 0 };
        ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32))
        {
            do
            {
                if (_tcscmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, lpszModuleName) == 0)
                {
                    dwModuleBaseAddress = (DWORD)ModuleEntry32.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    return dwModuleBaseAddress;
}

int main() {

    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, "Aplicacao");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    HANDLE AcessH = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

    DWORD baseAddr = GetModuleBaseAddress(pid, "aplicacao.exe");
    HP = baseAddr + 0x0072CFB0;
    HP += 0x140;
    HP += 0x234;
    HP += 0x204;
    HP += 0x10;
    HP += 0x1F8;
    HP += 0x248;
    HP += 0x490;
    std::cout << HP << std::endl;

        ReadProcessMemory(AcessH, (void*)HP, &value, sizeof(value), 0);
        std::cout << value << std::endl;

}
```